# Easy digital download EDD & Elementor Dynamic Tags

Tags: css, elementor, easy-digital-downloads

Q:
How to show/hide Elementor widget or assign Template for user who purchased EDD All Access Product in Easy digital download plugin

Check below Image showing issue:

[Normal user/ do not Purchased All Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNI9p.jpg)

[All Access subscriber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yro8C.jpg)

in another ways:
show Elementor widget or Pop up to all website visitor and asking them to subscribe to a plan by purchasing EDD Product called "All Access" to download anything, then hide that widget after user made a purchase of that "EDD All Access" Product.

I tried using Dynamic.ooo Plugin with Dynamic visibility if that widget, but its broke the template

[Elementor templates damaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TD4c.jpg)

Comment: hello and welcome, could you clarify your question and include some relevant code? this will help us to debug your issue (see [ask] and [example])

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.